# Can't use Ignition Gazebo thermal camera plugin with gpu lidar sensor

Tags: camera, sensors, lidar, gazebo-ignition, ignition-citadel

I am using Ignition Gazebo Citadel to simulate a differential drive robot, like https://gazebosim.org/docs/citadel/sensors. I am adding a thermal camera to the model (https://gazebosim.org/api/sensors/4.0/thermalcameraigngazebo.html). However, when the gpu_lidar sensor is included, the thermal camera cannot sense any of the objects, it only outputs the ambient temperature of the world. If I comment out the lidar sensor in the .sdf, I can visualize the thermal camera output of objects just fine. It's only when the lidar is included that the issue arises. I tried subscribing to /thermal_camera and that is how I know it is producing measurements, but only of the world temperature when lidar is enabled. I would think these sensors should act independently, but I am new to Gazebo, so any insight into how they may be affecting each other is much appreciated. Here is the code I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.7">
    <world name="sensor_world">
        <physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
            <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
            <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
        </physics>
        <plugin
            filename="ignition-gazebo-physics-system"
            name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics">
        </plugin>
        <plugin
            filename="ignition-gazebo-user-commands-system"
            name="ignition::gazebo::systems::UserCommands">
        </plugin>
        <plugin
            filename="ignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system"
            name="ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
        </plugin>
        <plugin filename="ignition-gazebo-imu-system"
                name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Imu">
        </plugin>
        <plugin filename="ignition-gazebo-sensors-system"
                name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors">
            <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
        </plugin>
        <plugin filename="ignition-gazebo-contact-system"
                name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Contact">
        </plugin>
        <gui fullscreen="0">

            <!-- 3D scene -->
            <plugin filename="GzScene3D" name="3D View">
                <ignition-gui>
                <title>3D View</title>
                <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
                <property type="string" key="state">docked</property>
                </ignition-gui>

                <engine>ogre2</engine>
                <scene>scene</scene>
                <ambient_light>0.4 0.4 0.4</ambient_light>
                <background_color>0.8 0.8 0.8</background_color>
            </plugin>

            <!-- World control -->
            <plugin filename="WorldControl" name="World control">
                <ignition-gui>
                <title>World control</title>
                <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
                <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
                <property type="double" key="height">72</property>
                <property type="double" key="width">121</property>
                <property type="double" key="z">1</property>

                <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
                <anchors target="3D View">
                    <line own="left" target="left"/>
                    <line own="bottom" target="bottom"/>
                </anchors>
                </ignition-gui>

                <play_pause>true</play_pause>
                <step>true</step>
                <start_paused>true</start_paused>
                <service>/world/sensor_world/control</service>
                <stats_topic>/world/sensor_world/stats</stats_topic>
            </plugin>

            <!-- World statistics -->
            <plugin filename="WorldStats" name="World stats">
                <ignition-gui>
                <title>World stats</title>
                <property type="bool" key="showTitleBar">false</property>
                <property type="bool" key="resizable">false</property>
                <property type="double" key="height">110</property>
                <property type="double" key="width">290</property>
                <property type="double" key="z">1</property>

                <property type="string" key="state">floating</property>
                <anchors target="3D View">
                    <line own="right" target="right"/>
                    <line own="bottom" target="bottom"/>
                </anchors>
                </ignition-gui>

                <sim_time>true</sim_time>
                <real_time>true</real_time>
                <real_time_factor>true</real_time_factor>
                <iterations>true</iterations>
                <topic>/world/sensor_world/stats</topic>

            </plugin>
            
             <plugin filename="ImageDisplay" name="Image Display">
                          <ignition-gui>
                            <title>Thermal camera</title>
                            <property key="state" type="string">floating</property>
                            <property type="double" key="width">350</property>
                            <property type="double" key="height">315</property>
                          </ignition-gui>
                          <topic>thermal_camera</topic>
                          <topic_picker>false</topic_picker>
                        </plugin>
                  

            <!-- Entity tree -->
            <plugin filename="EntityTree" name="Entity tree">
            </plugin>

            <!-- KeyPublisher plugin-->
            <plugin filename="KeyPublisher" name="Key Publisher"/>

        </gui>

        <light type="directional" name="sun">
            <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
            <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
            <attenuation>
                <range>1000</range>
                <constant>0.9</constant>
                <linear>0.01</linear>
                <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
            </attenuation>
            <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
        </light>
        
        <atmosphere type="adiabatic">
        <temperature>310</temperature>
        </atmosphere>

        <model name="ground_plane">
            <static>true</static>
            <link name="link">
                <collision name="collision">
                <geometry>
                    <plane>
                    <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                    </plane>
                </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="visual">
                <geometry>
                    <plane>
                    <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                    <size>100 100</size>
                    </plane>
                </geometry>
                <material>
                    <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
                    <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
                    <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
                </material>
                </visual>
            </link>
        </model>

        <model name='vehicle_blue' canonical_link='chassis'>
            <pose relative_to=world>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>   <!--the pose is relative to the world by default-->

            <frame name="lidar_frame" attached_to='chassis'>
                <pose>0.8 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
            </frame>

            <link name='chassis'>   
                <pose relative_to='__model__'>0.5 0 0.4 0 0 0</pose> 
                <inertial> <!--inertial properties of the link mass, inertia matix-->
                    <mass>1.14395</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.126164</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.416519</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.481014</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <box>
                            <size>2.0 1.0 0.5</size> <!--question: this size is in meter-->
                        </box>
                    </geometry>
                    <!--let's add color to our link-->
                    <material>
                        <ambient>0.0 0.0 1.0 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>0.0 0.0 1.0 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>0.0 0.0 1.0 1</specular>
                    </material>
                    <plugin
                                            filename="ignition-gazebo-thermal-system"
                                            name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Thermal">
                                            <temperature>100.0</temperature>
                                        </plugin>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'> <!--todo: describe why we need the collision-->
                    <geometry>
                        <box>
                            <size>2.0 1.0 0.5</size>
                        </box>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
                <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
                    <always_on>1</always_on>
                    <update_rate>1</update_rate>
                    <visualize>true</visualize>
                    <topic>imu</topic>
                </sensor>
                <comment>
                <sensor name='gpu_lidar' type='gpu_lidar'>"
                    <pose relative_to='lidar_frame'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
                    <topic>lidar</topic>
                    <update_rate>10</update_rate>
                    <ray>
                    <scan>
                        <horizontal>
                        <samples>640</samples>
                        <resolution>1</resolution>
                        <min_angle>-1.396263</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>1.396263</max_angle>
                        </horizontal>
                        <vertical>
                        <samples>1</samples>
                        <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                        <min_angle>0</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>0</max_angle>
                        </vertical>
                    </scan>
                    <range>
                        <min>0.08</min>
                        <max>10.0</max>
                        <resolution>0.01</resolution>
                    </range>
                    </ray>
                    <alwaysOn>1</alwaysOn>
                    <visualize>true</visualize>
                </sensor>
                </comment>
            </link>

            <!--let's build the left wheel-->
            <link name='left_wheel'> 
                <pose relative_to="chassis">-0.5 0.6 0 -1.5707 0 0</pose> <!--angles are in radian-->
                <inertial>
                    <mass>2</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.145833</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.145833</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.125</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.4</radius> 
                            <length>0.2</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                    <material>
                        <ambient>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</specular>
                    </material>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.4</radius>
                            <length>0.2</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
            </link>

            <!--copy and paste for right wheel but change position-->
            <link name='right_wheel'>
                <pose relative_to="chassis">-0.5 -0.6 0 -1.5707 0 0</pose> <!--angles are in radian-->
                <inertial>
                    <mass>1</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.145833</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.145833</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.125</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.4</radius>
                            <length>0.2</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                    <material>
                        <ambient>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</specular>
                    </material>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.4</radius>
                            <length>0.2</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
            </link>

            <frame name="caster_frame" attached_to='chassis'>
                <pose>0.8 0 -0.2 0 0 0</pose>
            </frame>

            <!--caster wheel-->
            <link name='caster'>
                <pose relative_to='caster_frame'/>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>1</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.1</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.1</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.1</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <sphere>
                            <radius>0.2</radius>
                        </sphere>
                    </geometry>
                    <material>
                        <ambient>0.0 1 0.0 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>0.0 1 0.0 1 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>0.0 1 0.0 1</specular>
                    </material>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'>
                    <geometry>
                        <sphere>
                            <radius>0.2</radius>
                        </sphere>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
            </link>

            <!--connecting these links together using joints-->
            <joint name='left_wheel_joint' type='revolute'> <!--continous joint is not supported yet-->
                <pose relative_to='left_wheel'/>
                <parent>chassis</parent>
                <child>left_wheel</child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz expressed_in='__model__'>0 1 0</xyz> <!--can be descired to any frame or even arbitrary frames-->
                    <limit>
                        <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>    <!--negative infinity-->
                        <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>     <!--positive infinity-->
                    </limit>
                </axis>
            </joint>

            <joint name='right_wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
                <pose relative_to='right_wheel'/>
                <parent>chassis</parent>
                <child>right_wheel</child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz expressed_in='__model__'>0 1 0</xyz>
                    <limit>
                        <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>    <!--negative infinity-->
                        <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>     <!--positive infinity-->
                    </limit>
                </axis>
            </joint>

            <!--different type of joints ball joint--> <!--defult value is the child-->
            <joint name='caster_wheel' type='ball'>
                <parent>chassis</parent>
                <child>caster</child>
            </joint>

            <!--diff drive plugin-->
            <plugin
                filename="ignition-gazebo-diff-drive-system"
                name="ignition::gazebo::systems::DiffDrive">
                <left_joint>left_wheel_joint</left_joint>
                <right_joint>right_wheel_joint</right_joint>
                <wheel_separation>1.2</wheel_separation>
                <wheel_radius>0.4</wheel_radius>
                <odom_publish_frequency>1</odom_publish_frequency>
                <topic>cmd_vel</topic>
            </plugin>
        </model>

                <!-- Thermal camera --> 
                <model name="thermal_camera">
                <pose>4.5 0 0.5 0.0 0.0 3.14</pose>
                <link name="link">
                    <pose>0.05 0.05 0.05 0 0 0</pose>
                    <collision name="collision">
                        <geometry>
                          <box>
                            <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
                          </box>
                        </geometry>
                    </collision>
                    <visual name="visual">
                        <geometry>
                          <box>
                            <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
                          </box>
                        </geometry>
                    </visual>
                    <sensor name="thermal_camera" type="thermal">
                        <camera>
                          <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
                          <image>
                            <width>320</width>
                            <height>240</height>
                          </image>
                          <clip>
                            <near>0.1</near>
                            <far>100</far>
                          </clip>
                        </camera>
                        <always_on>1</always_on>
                        <update_rate>30</update_rate>
                        <visualize>true</visualize>
                        <topic>thermal_camera</topic>
                    </sensor>
                </link>
                <static>true</static>
            </model>

    </world>
</sdf>
```

The output should look like this, but if you uncomment the lidar, the camera output will be all black.
[image: Output without lidar sensor]